# HTML (Email) 3-column table: How to align content within columns

Tags: html, email, html-table

I'm trying to create an HTML email with a section that has 3 columns. I want the columns to align so that the buttons and the backgrounds used in each section align horizontally, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this across different email providers. I think I see how to make the backgrounds line up, but I'm not sure about how to get the buttons in the 3 columns to align. When it aligns in Gmail, it doesn't in Outlook, etc.

Here is what I have right now:
http://jsfiddle.net/UT7ZD/166/

```css
table {
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td div {
  height: 100%;
}
.ReadMsgBody {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.ExternalClass {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: Georgia, Times, serif
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {
    width: 440px!important;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body[yahoo] .center {
    text-align: center!important;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  body[yahoo] .deviceWidth {
    width: 280px!important;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body[yahoo] .center {
    text-align: center!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<table width="580" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="deviceWidth" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin:0 auto;">
  <td>
    <table width="32%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="deviceWidth" bgcolor="#ffede1">
      <td height="280px" style="padding:10px 10px 20px 10px">
        <div>
          <center>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing euas magni quod error quidem incidunt eius qui consequatur ab asperiores optio similique ex reiciendis!
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br><a href="https://www.website.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 12px; border-width: 8px 20px; border-style: solid; border-color: #1675a9; display: inline-block; background-color: #1675a9;"><b>Button 1 </b></a>
          </center>
        </div>
      </td>
    </table>
    <table width="32%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="deviceWidth">
      <td height="280px" style="padding:10px 10px 20px 10px">
        <div>
          <center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad omnis quae expedita ipsum nobis praesentium velit animi minus amet perspiciatis laboriosam similique debitis iste ratione nemo ea at corporis aliquam.
            <br>
            <br><a href="https://www.website.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 12px; border-width: 8px 20px; border-style: solid; border-color: #1675a9; display: inline-block; background-color: #1675a9;"><b>Button 2</b></a>
          </center>
        </div>
      </td>
    </table>
    <table width="32%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="deviceWidth" bgcolor="#ffede1">
      <td height="280px" style="padding:10px 10px 20px 10px">

        <div>
          <center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum dolferendis ullam consequatur.
            <br>
            <br><a href="https://www.website.com" target="_blank" style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; border-radius: 12px; border-width: 8px 20px; border-style: solid; border-color: #1675a9; display: inline-block; background-color: #1675a9;"><b>Button 3</b></a>
          </center>
        </div>
      </td>
    </table>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question

Comment: Your html is broken, td is not allowed as a child element for table, you are missing the <tr>-elements. Also you are missing the ending tags for td an table.

Comment: What's the use of a table if only one cell is inside it?

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/UT7ZD/168/
Also learn HTML. You can use use `@media`queries but don't know how to add simple rows or cells to a table
You might find [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) useful in that.